# fitting texts inside a stack

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a stack contains two texts .. sometimes one of the text is really long and it will be in two lines like this:

[image]

So i tried to use FittedBox like this:

```
new Container(
                                                height: 44.0,
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius
                                                      .all(const Radius
                                                          .circular(30.0)),
                                                  border: new Border.all(
                                                      color:
                                                          Color(0xff606060),
                                                      width: 2.5),
                                                ),
                                                child: new Stack(
                                                  children: <Widget>[
                                                    Align(
                                                      alignment: globals
                                                                  .currentLang ==
                                                              'ar'
                                                          ? Alignment
                                                              .centerRight
                                                          : Alignment
                                                              .centerLeft,
                                                      child: Padding(
                                                        padding:
                                                            EdgeInsets.only(
                                                                right: 15.0,
                                                                left: 15.0),
                                                        child:  FittedBox(
                                                          fit: BoxFit
                                                              .contain,
                                                          child: Text(
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                    Align(
                                                      alignment: globals
                                                                  .currentLang ==
                                                              'ar'
                                                          ? Alignment
                                                              .centerLeft
                                                          : Alignment
                                                              .centerRight,
                                                      child: Padding(
                                                        padding:
                                                            EdgeInsets.only(
                                                                left: 15.0,
                                                                right:
                                                                    15.0),
                                                        child: new Text(
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
```

and i got this result:

[image]

I want a space between the two texts so it will not be covered by each other .. how to solve this?

UPDATE:

[image]

UPDATE 2:

[image]

Comment: Why would you use a `Stack` widget if you don't want the two `Text` widgets overlap?

Comment: @JeromeEscalante then how to do it? and align each text to the side .. i mean one at the right and the other at the left

Comment: Would using Column rather than Stack do what you want?

Comment: @ChrisReynolds can you show me an example please? how column when i want them beside each other?

Comment: @mrs.tat - check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this solution if it is ok for you to scale only text aligned to the right.

```
Container(
    height: 44.0,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(30.0)),
        border: Border.all(color: Color(0xff606060), width: 2.5),
    ),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
            Text('Some text'),
            SizedBox(width: 8.0),
            Expanded(
                child: FittedBox(
                    fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                    child: Text(
                        'Demo text. Long demo text. Duplicated long demo text.',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.end
                    )
                )
            )
        ],
    ),
)
```

[image]

UPDATE:

Flex instead of Row and Expanded looks better. Check it out

```
Flex(
                      direction: Axis.horizontal,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                          Flexible(child: Text('10%'), flex: 0, fit: FlexFit.tight,),
                          SizedBox(width: 8.0),
                          Flexible(
                              flex: 1,
                              fit: FlexFit.loose,
                              child: FittedBox(
                                  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                  child: Text(
                                      'Demo text. Demo text. Demo text. Demo text. Demo text.',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.start
                                  ),
                              )
                          )
                      ],
                  )
```

Comment: okay.. this does what i want .. but if the text is short theres a padding before it .. how to solve this?

Comment: if you can check the last screenshot in my post please

Comment: actually solved that problem, but the text which is not a child of expanded .. is not in the center of the row horizontally.. how to solve this?

Comment: I think I found a right solution. Try to use Flex and Flexible instead of Row and Expanded

Comment: Please check update of my answer. You have to set mainAxisAlignment of Flex to center and user Flex for both texts with flex = 0.

Comment: Flex doesn't work with FittedBox. So update doesn't resolve issue.

Comment: To make Flexible working with FittedBox you have to set flex: 1, fit: FlexFit.loose. I also updated answer with complete code example.

Comment: this returned them to be in the center both of them if the text is short

Comment: Actually i just edited the padding in the container and your first solution worked perfectly